# Fill a NumericMatrix with a single value on construction

Tags: rcpp

I'm trying to fill a NumericMatrix with a single value on construction. As an example, consider the following:

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
void test() {
  NumericMatrix res(1, 1, NA_REAL);
}
```

This is throwing the error of:

```
error: call to constructor of 'Vector<14, PreserveStorage>' is ambiguous
        VECTOR( start, start + (static_cast<R_xlen_t>(nrows_)*ncols) ),
        ^       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
file46e92f4e027d.cpp:6:17: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'Rcpp::Matrix<14, PreserveStorage>::Matrix<double>' requested here
  NumericMatrix res(1, 1, NA_REAL);

/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/library/Rcpp/include/Rcpp/vector/Vector.h:88:5: note: candidate constructor [with T = double]
    Vector( const T& size, const stored_type& u,
    ^
/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/library/Rcpp/include/Rcpp/vector/Vector.h:211:5: note: candidate constructor [with InputIterator = double]
    Vector( InputIterator first, InputIterator last){
    ^
```

Why is a `NumericMatrix` unable to be instantiated with a single value alongside fixed dimensions?

Comment: I think this is as simple as there simple not being a matching constructor for what you called. Nothing more, nothing less.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So in short this works (one longer line broken in three for display):

```
> Rcpp::cppFunction("NumericVector fp() { 
+     NumericVector res(3,NA_REAL); 
+     return res;}")
> fp()
[1] NA NA NA  
>
```

but there is no matching constructor using *rows, cols* for matrices.  So you have to use what vectors give you above, and set dimensions by hand.

For example via (where I had it all in one line which I broke up here for exposition)

```
> Rcpp::cppFunction("NumericMatrix fp(int n, int k) { 
+         NumericVector res(n*k,NA_REAL); 
+         res.attr(\"dim\") = IntegerVector::create(n,k); 
+         return NumericMatrix(res);}")
> fp(2,3)
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]   NA   NA   NA
[2,]   NA   NA   NA
>
```

Comment: Okay, I assumed I could specify the value for all elements as in the vector case. I've solved this by now using `.fill()`.

Answer (score 1):

Not to usurp Dirk, but there isn't a need to set the dimensions of the matrix with `.attr()`.

Filling a matrix, unlike a vector, requires supplying an iterator with `n * p` elements alongside dimensions for the constructor.

```cpp
Matrix(const int& nrows_, const int& ncols, Iterator start)
```

For other constructors, please see: [`inst/include/Rcpp/vector/Matrix.h`](https://github.com/RcppCore/Rcpp/blob/d7e50fea50489b7490c8f14f4a802862e398a79d/inst/include/Rcpp/vector/Matrix.h#L51-L81)

With this in mind, the original example can be changed to:

```cpp
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
Rcpp::NumericMatrix matrix_fill_by_vec(int n, int p) {

  // fill matrix using a vector
  Rcpp::NumericVector A = Rcpp::NumericVector(n * p, NA_REAL); 
  Rcpp::NumericMatrix B = Rcpp::NumericMatrix(n, p, A.begin());

  return B;
}
```

Taking it for a test drive, we get:

```
matrix_fill_by_vec(3, 2)
#      [,1] [,2]
# [1,]   NA   NA
# [2,]   NA   NA
# [3,]   NA   NA
```